# Argument sweep in gnu parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

I would like to run a parameter sweep of the command line argument of a command. The command is:

```
mycommand --fixed arg 5 --variable_arg 0
```

and I would like to vary variable_arg from 0-100. How can I do this in a single command using gnu parallel, which generating a separate file with all the individual commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
parallel mycommand --fixed arg 5 --variable_arg {} ::: {0..100}
```

If you want the result in `myout.1` .. `myout.100` you can use one of these:

```
parallel --results myout.{} mycommand --fixed arg 5 --variable_arg {} ::: {0..100}
parallel mycommand --fixed arg 5 --variable_arg {} '>' myout.{} ::: {0..100}
```